# passing information from one jframe to another

Tags: java, swing

To begin with, I know that using multiple jframes is frowned upon, unfortunately i have gotten myself to deep into this project to start over. my issue is i cannot find a way to transfer data (user input) from one frame to another, i will provide the code i need to be transferred from frame 1 to another frame

this is my code for the name and email they have to input

```
    JTextArea txtrEnterYourFull = new JTextArea();
    txtrEnterYourFull.setEditable(false);
    txtrEnterYourFull.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    txtrEnterYourFull.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    txtrEnterYourFull.setText("Enter your full name");
    txtrEnterYourFull.setBounds(52, 58, 166, 29);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtrEnterYourFull);



    nameL = new JTextField();
    nameL.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    }
    );
    nameL.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    nameL.setBounds(52, 93, 284, 26);
    frame.getContentPane().add(nameL);
    nameL.setColumns(10);


    JTextArea txtroptionalEnterYour = new JTextArea();
    txtroptionalEnterYour.setEditable(false);
    txtroptionalEnterYour.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    txtroptionalEnterYour.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    txtroptionalEnterYour.setText("(Optional) Enter your email");
    txtroptionalEnterYour.setBounds(52, 139, 193, 29);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtroptionalEnterYour);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
```

here is the button code to go to the new frame

```
    JButton btnContinue = new JButton("Continue");
    btnContinue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            frame2 fram = new frame2 ();
            fram.setVisible(true);
            frame.dispose();
```

i am new to swing and i dont need someone to complete my program. i just need to know how to carry it over to a new text box on a new frame.

Comment: Not sure where you got confused, you just have to use `getText()` on the `JTextArea` and use `setText()` on the other. Could you provide the whole code for the class?

Comment: *"i have gotten myself to deep into this project to start over."* Tough luck. There is no point to continuing with inherently broken code. It will take longer to fix that mess, than refactor the app. to ***not*** be inherently broken.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is trying to fix an inherently broken approach. 

We cannot fix a broken leg with band-aids.

Comment: `txtrEnterYourFull.setBounds(52, 58, 166, 29);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: I think this question is duplicated, here you can found an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382999/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-one-jframe-to-another/20383247#20383247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this is fairly easy. All you need to do is to set a constructor in which you are passing your frame with the values you need over to your new frame.

For example, I have a LoginScreen.java and DoctorScreen.java. If my user successfully entered his details and logs in, I transfer an ArrayList of Doctors from one JFrame to another JFrame, or more precisely, from one java class to another by creating a new instance of that class

Example here

Passing an arraylist from LoginScreen.java to DoctorScreen.java

```
DoctorScreen dScreen = new DoctorScreen(frame, docList,d);
```

Now Taking those values passed from LoginScreen.java and setting them in DoctorScreen.java

```
public DoctorScreen(JFrame frame, ArrayList<Doctor> docList, Doctor d) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    dialog = new JFileChooser(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    this.frame = frame;
    this.docList = docList;
    this.d = d;
    initialize();
}
```

Now, you can change the DoctorScreen Constructor to fit into whatever project you are trying to do.

The steps I would advise you to take is to create a Java file for handling your input, and the second Java file to display what you entered in the first file

EG:

```
JButton btnContinue = new JButton("Continue");
btnContinue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       String field1 = txtrEnterYourFull.getText();
       String name = nameL.getText();
       String field2 = txtroptionalEnterYour.getText();

       Display display = new Display(name, field1, field2);//using this as example
}

}
```

Then in your display.java, call your constructor taking in these fields and display them either in a textfield/textarea or in a JLabel in your frame

```
 String name, field1, field2;

 public Display(String name, String field1, String field2){

     this.name = name;
     this.field1 = field1;
     this.field2 - field2;
 }
```

Please take note that these variables have already been declared and I am merely using this for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Frames are like any other class, so just use the same kind of strategies you use to pass data between any other classes. For example you can simply create setter methods in your second frame class and call them from the first frame.

**Note**: This is just something I threw together really fast in Netbeans so there is a lot of generated code. Also, this is strictly an example I'm not saying it's necessarily the *best* way to do this.

Here is a quick and dirty example of how you might pass data between two `JFrame` objects:

This is the code to pay attention to from Frame1:

```
private void sendToOtherFrameBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        Frame2 otherFrame = new Frame2();
        otherFrame.setTextFieldText(jTextField1.getText());
        otherFrame.setTextAreaText(jTextArea1.getText());
        otherFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Here is the full code for Frame1:

```
public class Frame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Frame1
     */
    public Frame1() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        sendToOtherFrameBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jTextArea1.setText("text area data");
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jTextField1.setText("text field data");

        sendToOtherFrameBtn.setText("Send To Other Frame");
        sendToOtherFrameBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                sendToOtherFrameBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(99, 99, 99)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 166, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(115, 115, 115)
                        .addComponent(sendToOtherFrameBtn)))
                .addContainerGap(135, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 37, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(sendToOtherFrameBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(31, 31, 31))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void sendToOtherFrameBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        Frame2 otherFrame = new Frame2();
        otherFrame.setTextFieldText(jTextField1.getText());
        otherFrame.setTextAreaText(jTextArea1.getText());
        otherFrame.setVisible(true);
    }                                                   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Frame1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JButton sendToOtherFrameBtn;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here is the important code from Frame2:

```
public void setTextFieldText(String txt){
    jTextField1.setText(txt);
}

public void setTextAreaText(String txt){
    jTextArea1.setText(txt);
}
```

Here is the full code for Frame2:

```
public class Frame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Frame2
     */
    public Frame2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void setTextFieldText(String txt){
        jTextField1.setText(txt);
    }

    public void setTextAreaText(String txt){
        jTextArea1.setText(txt);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(111, 111, 111)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1))
                .addContainerGap(123, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(52, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(99, 99, 99))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Frame2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer and remove the extra bits? or can I?