# How to send data to another frame with java

Tags: java, user-interface

So I have my program open a new frame but I need information to send to the other frame from what the user input. What is the quickest way to have a java application send data to another frame. Examples or anything will help please.

Comment: Please could you show us the code that you have so far?

Comment: Already solved: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242807/passing-information-from-one-jframe-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242807/passing-information-from-one-jframe-to-another)