# Java swing put extra some data in another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two Java Swing classes. I want to put extra some `String` in second Swing GUI on button click. I wrote code to can show second `JFrame`, but I don't know how to put some data (name, last name or etc).

This is my button listener code:

```
DetailsGUI detailsGUI=new DetailsGUI();
detailsGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
detailsGUI.pack();
detailsGUI.setVisible(true);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: *"Also ,is it a possible .."* SO is a Q&A site where each thread should have a single, specific question. When it comes to 'also', split that into a separate thread.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20383247/1670134